# .getText() элемента из fxml

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу получить текст из элемента surname_visitor. Вылетает `NullPointerException`.

FXML:

```
<TextField fx:id="passport_visitor" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="2816765432" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM" />
            <TextField fx:id="surname_visitor" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="Иванов" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM" />
            <TextField fx:id="name_visitor" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="Иван" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM" />
            <TextField fx:id="phone_visitor" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="89121120975" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM" />
            <TextField fx:id="otchestvo_visitor" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="Иванович" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM" />
```

Controller:

```
public class add_visitorController  {


@FXML
public static Button add_new_visitor;  //функция add_new

@FXML
public static TextField surname_visitor; 

void add_new(ActionEvent event) {
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
     
        alert.setContentText(surname_visitor.getText());

        alert.showAndWait();


} 
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.TextField.getText()" because 
"sample.add_visitorController.surname_visitor" is null
```

Укажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так.

Comment: изменила модификатор поля на private и перед методом добавила @FXML, живём-живём. гугля, наткнулась на `implements Initialize` и соответствующий метод, но особо не поняла, что это и зачем. буду рада, если объясните.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас поля контроллера статические. Грубо говоря ваш Контроллер пытается вытащить текст из пустого `TextField`, а не того, что у вас в `FXML` прописан. Просто уберите `static`.
Если возникает проблема с передачей поля другим классам, то вы в этот класс передавайте ссылку на ваш `TextField` используя `this`.

Что касается `public void initialize(){}` код указанный в этих скобках, сработает перед сборкой всего приложения. Здесь нужно быть очень аккуратным, потому что любая неграмотная работа с неинициализированной переменной или полем, вызовет краш.Например IDE IDEA вообще даже не выдает в подсказках этот метод, его можно прописать только вручную, на свой страх и риск так сказать...

Так же не совсем понятно, по вашему коду, связан ли вообще контроллер с файлом FXML. Вот пример связки.

```
<Pane fx:id="mainPain" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="900.0"
style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
fx:controller="sample.startController.Controller" />
```

Обратить внимание на : `fx:controller=` путь к файлу где точка это указание
пакета(пути/папки)

```
package sample.startController;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

    public class Controller {
    
        @FXML
        private Pane mainPain;
    
        public void initialize(){
            // Some code
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: `Controller` должен быть `implement Initializable`